# What is the best way to measure the width of a glowing object along its height?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, edge-detection

What is the best way to measure the width (perpendicular distance) of this glowing object along its height?

Adding some context:

1. Is the bright orange surrounding stable?
   Yes, it is. These objects are very hot (about 1000 degrees) and, therefore, incandescent. As the middle one is closer to the camera, it looks darker.
2. Does it cover the whole background or is it left and right of the object, but not behind it?
   The background is a wall at room temperature (about 15 degrees) and will therefore always be 'black'.
3. Can you assume that the center of the image is always inside of the object?
   I am using a model to detect and localize the object and always extract the Region of Interest in this way. So yes, we can assume that the frames will always look like this: three bright objects with one in the middle slightly darker than the others in a 475 x 1079 frame with a black background.
4. Why is there a rapid (but noisy) switch from very bright (bottom) to very dark (top) in the object? Is that switch always in about at that position?
   This is due to the difference in temperature. The bottom of the object is warmer than the top, so there is a change in brightness.
   This change is similar in all objects. Sometimes there is a little dust (black spots) that happens 20% of the time and mostly on the upper part of the object but we can ignore it. I thought about dividing the image (the object actually) into 10 pieces, for example, and ignoring the ones with these black spots.

Here is an example of what I would like to achieve:

[image]

Here are the steps I have performed so far:

Original picture:

[image: Original image]

Dark spots:

[image]

Equalization of the histogram of the Y channel:

```
img_yuv[:,:,0] = cv2.equalizeHist(img_yuv[:,:,0])
```

[image: Channel y equalized]

Denoising by applying fastNlMeansDenoisingColored:

```
temporary_image = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(temporary_image, None, 10, 10, 7, 21)
```

[image: image after removing the noise]

Then I tried 3 things:

1. To filter by color:

   `hMin = 15`

   `sMin = 92`

   `vMin = 120`

   `hMax = 25`

   `sMax = 147`

   `vMax = 255`

   `# Set minimum and max HSV values to display`

   `lower = np.array([hMin, sMin, vMin])`

   `upper = np.array([hMax, sMax, vMax])`

   `# Create HSV Image and threshold into a range.`

   `hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)`

   `mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)`

   `output = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask= mask)`

[image: Image filtered by color]

2. To use gradient:

[image: Image after using gradiente]

3. To use Canny Edge Detection:

[image: Image after using Canny]

The problem I'm facing is finding a single line or structure that I can trust to measure it from.
I am finding a lot of noise even after the filtering process.

Any ideas or recommendations?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: please also provide the code for the image processing you are doing so that others can use that to update and suggest next steps that might solve your problem

Comment: you need to acquire the image differently. you need that glowing object (everything glows there!) to contrast clearly against the rest of the picture. and you should show various pictures to represent the *variation* of that thing. -- discard all the filtering attempts so far. everything, beginning with histogram equalization, leads nowhere.

Comment: Can you explain the content? Is the bright orange surrounding stable? Does it cover the whole background or is it left and right of the object, but not behind it? Can you assume that the center of the image is always inside of the object? Can you assume that the center vertical line is always inside of the object? Why is there a rapid (but noisy) switch from very bright (bottom) to very dark (top) in the object? Is that switch always in about at that position?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal I added some code for the more complex functions. Let me know if more is needed.

Comment: @Micka Thanks for your comments. I added all this information to the description of the problem. Actually, I just did not understand the question regarding the center vertical line.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for your commets. Considering that is not possible to acquire the image differently, do you see another way to achieve the goal that I mentioned before?

Comment: thank you for the comments, that make the content much clearer to me. So the bright orange surroundings are additional objects further away and they can probably differ in their width as well, so they are quite stable but can't be assumed to be constant or sth.. I think I would start in the vertical middle line of the object and try to find possible contour candidates (per row) by finding gradients to the outside. Then in a second step try to find the most probable overall contour with assumptions that from one row to the next the position change can't be too strong.

Comment: Measuring the width where you don't see the object is cheating. You should not do that.